# App config asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, app-config

Let's say I have a class called AppConfig:

```
public static class AppConfig
{
    private static XDocument config = 

    public static AppConfig()
    {

    }
}
```

How do I XDocument.Load the ~App.Config file? Isn't it something like Server.SOMETHING? What namespaces do I need to include>

Comment: In ASP.NET you typically have a web.config - not an app.config.....

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? To parse custom sections in a web.config, this is the way to go: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309045

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what is his problem, he is not able to get server class in his class

Server is property of the Page class that your page inherits from, it not a
global. if you are trying to access from a class, use

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("");
```

and add reference

```
using System.Web;
```

OR can be get directly

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/web.config"));
```

is probably what you're looking for. This helper class "Server" lives on the "current" HttpContext inside the System.Web namespace, so add a

```
using System.Web;
```

to your code.

Marc

Comment: @Muhammad: you're absolutely right, my oversight - it's part of the HttpContext, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're trying to do that ... if you want to access the values in your web.config or app.config (for client apps) there is already a wrapper class set up to do that named My.Settings.

Those app.config and web.config files are a pain in the keester to deal with directly.